# .open() in VB.net for MySQL database returns System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Given key missing from dictionary. How to fix it?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, database-connection, visual-studio-2019

I want to connect my Visual Basic project to a MySQL Database. I tried it in an empty project and I succeeded.

But when I try to connect to my hosted project on Windows IIS with the function `.Open()`, it returns this error below :

The error is on the line `a_Conn.Open()`

```vb
Dim connStr As String = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=*******;user id=admin;pwd=root"
Dim a_Conn As New MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connStr)
a_Conn.open() ' <-- the error
```

System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Given key missing from the dictionary.

```
[KeyNotFoundException: Given key missing from dictionary.]
       System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException() +36
       System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +52
       MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetChararcterSet(DBVersion version, String CharSetName) +33
       MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetEncoding(DBVersion version, String CharSetName) +19
       MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Configure(MySqlConnection connection) +969
       MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Configure(MySqlConnection conn) +16
       MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +464
       System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +172
       System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +178
       System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet) +122
       ******.generic.Tools.DataTableQuery(String sql, String table) in C:\path\to\file\generic\Tools.vb:483
```

Pardon my english

Comment: You should check/compare the values in the app.config and web.config for differences and also the project references to make sure they are the same

Comment: I'm not convinced this is the code you are actually running. I don't see how that error can be caused by that code.

Comment: @JayV thanks you for your answer but in  which domain do I have to check the differences because they are very long ?

Comment: @Crowcoder I agree with you and I can show you the result of pile execution